# How to implement JSF generic component

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I'm new to JSF - I need to implement a generic panel that, based on clicking on btn1 or btn2 shows panel1 or panel2. What is the best way to do this?

**Edit**

One of the things I want to do is encapsulate some logic within each implementation of the generic component - I don't know if composites are the best way to achieve it, even though I know I can pass values/methods into the composite via attributes

Comment: The best way is to actually learn the basics of JSF first. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've been studying composites but it feels like stretching a long way to do something simple. One of the things I want to do is encapsulate some logic within each implementation of the generic component - I don't know if composites are the best way to achieve it, even though I know I can pass values/methods into the composite via attributes.

Comment: Composites are very much not the basics. Do you know how to create a simple page with two buttons and clicking on either button updates what is shown on screen?

Comment: Yes, the page is created, the buttons are there. Now I want to do this <panel id="genericPanel" rendered=false />; on btn1 I want to instantiante genericPanel as PanelA; on btn2, PanelB, and so on. I am aware that I can simply place 2 panels <panel id="panelA" /> and <panel id="panelB" />, but I just wanted to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Still no decent example (http://sscce.org/), only a vague high level description. Unanswerable at this point in my opinion. A composite component -might- do it, but it would all depend on what is rendered inside PanelA and PanelB and what kind of backing beans are involved. Perhaps a simple ui:include can also work. I cannot know, you provide nothing that might help to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to stick with for now `<ui:include>` - seems simpler.